# In select query, set column value, based on if -else if condition in q kdb

Tags: kdb

We have a table t:

```
t:([] sym:`GOOG`IBM`APPL; px:10 20 30; size:1000 2000 3000)
```

Now we want to select assign a column in output based on a condition provided in a function.

```
{[m]select sym, px, size, eb:?[`ab=m;`cd;`ef] from t where size>1000}[`ab] / This works fine providing proper value to eb in output(if/else)
```

But my requirement is based on (if/else if) to set the value of eb as below, tried ?, $ but didn't work

```
{[m]select sym, px, size, eb:?[`ab=m;`cd;`yz=m;`ef] from t where size>1000}[`ab] / It fails with type error
```

requirement(Sudo code):

```
if (m==ab) { return cd};
else if (m==yz) {return ef};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using vector conditional `?` you need to nest the conditionals. In this example not matching either condition will return a null.

```
q){[m]select sym, px, size, eb:?[`ab=m;`cd;?[`yz=m;`ef;`]] from t where size>1000}[`ab]
sym  px size eb
---------------
IBM  20 2000 cd
APPL 30 3000 cd
```

If you have a lot of discrete conditions this can become very unwieldy, an alternative would be to use a dictionary.

```
q)dict:`ab`yz!`cd`ef
q){[m]select sym, px, size, eb:dict[m] from t where size>1000}[`ab]
sym  px size eb
---------------
IBM  20 2000 cd
APPL 30 3000 cd
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the [find [?]](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/find/) operator to define a function to build that column:

```
q)f:{`cd`ef` `ab`yz?x}
q)f[`ab]
`cd
q)f[`yz]
`ef
q)f[`jk] // no match
`
q)select sym, px, size, eb:f[`ab] from t where size>1000
sym  px size eb
---------------
IBM  20 2000 cd
APPL 30 3000 cd
```